# Remove Shards from SOLR Database

Tags: solr

I recently recovered a SOLR database that uses SOLR cloud to shard an index.  I now have that database running on a single machine, but the data is still sharded--moreover now this is unnecessary.

How can I stop using SOLR cloud and merge these shards into a single collection?

Comment: Appears that it is not included out-of-the-box http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Why-does-SolrCloud-not-support-merge-shard-yet-td4142182.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the [Lucene Merge Index](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/MergingSolrIndexes) tool.  The SOLR approaches did not work for me (obtuse errors).